# easy beginner's query regarding sprites

Tags: css, css-sprites

HTML snippet:

```
<li class = "li_image"></li>
```

CSS snippet:

```css
li_img {
    width:28px;
    height:32px;
    background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_90902864.png) 10 15;
}
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? This list item is not even appearing in the list.

Comment: What are those "10 15"... px, ems, % .... you should assign them something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the dot before the class.
Also, what are you trying to aim with the "10" and "15"?
If you're trying to set width and height, state those inside of the class instead, just like you did.

It should be:

```css
.li_img {
    width:28px;
    height:32px;
    background:url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_90902864.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out there was a mismatch between my class name and call. (li_image vs. li_img) . Whoops.

Comment: Ah... No chosen answer then? :(